# Github pages doesn't read the .html and .js inside a folder

Tags: github-pages

I want to upload some webpage to test GitHub pages but I have a problem because it just shows the index.html and not the style.css and script.js that are inside the style and scripts folders.

[image]

I already have my link.
[image]

Comment: Your site is running normal for me. Do you wanted to have your page reflected on Github instead?

Comment: I don't know what happened suddenly after 18 min the page was loaded entirely. Maybe is just a question to wait a little more time after loading everything.

Comment: Yeah, patience is the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the solution was... I have just to put "./" before every root I have taken.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the side-effect of [a recent GitHub incident](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/wdhkj70kynwk)

> GitHub Pages is now experiencing degraded performance. We are continuing to investigate.

While the incident has been resolved, GitHub pages are not processed *immediately*.
Hopefully, performance will improve.